# HP EB 840 G1 keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard

this is my laptops HP EB 840 G1 keyboard layout.  do any body know which country's keyboard layout is this? every key is working properly and typing other symbols written on this key layout. I am surfing from last one year with this issue. Thanks in advance

[image: HP EB 840 G1 KEYBOARD Layout]

Comment: The country where it was originally purchased should give a clue. Or just googling the serial number and/or part number and/or full model number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Norwegian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QWERTY#Norwegian)

[image]

It's similar to Danish but the Ø and Æ are swapped.